# How to add controller support in a Blazor WASM project

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I want to have a server web app that serves the code for a Blazor WebAssembly app and also uses controllers to serve data.

So, **in a single server app (and in a single executable file)**, I want to pack the Blazor code that ships to the browser and also have the controllers to respond to HTTP requests.

I was expecting this to be easy to do, but I am honestly lost trying to find how to do this.

The Blazor WASM templates in Visual Studio don't seem to allow this out-of-the-box (the hosting model and what you can do with it is completely different from what you have in web apps) and searching online did not provide any helpful samples on how to do this.

Has anyone done this before?

**Note**:
I have started with a Blazor app and tried adding controller support to it. Not sure if starting with a web app and trying to add Blazor WebAssembly functionality to it would be easier, but I doubt it...

Comment: When you create a new Blazor Wasm app and check `[x] asp.net hosted` you get exactly what you describe. That _"completely different from what you have in web apps"_ is a litle vague, you could ask about that in moore detail.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks a lot. That seems to do the trick. What I meant was that, if you don't specify the option you mentioned, you don't get the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host`, nor a `Startup` class, but only a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder` that does not help much. It never crossed my mind that those initial checkboxes could affect things in that manner... If you want to make your comment an answer, I can accept it. :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hm... But with this option it creates a client and a server project. And they both have a `Program.cs`, so I guess it is not a single process anymore, is it? I wonder why it is so hard to have them both in a single project/process. This is really annoying...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I guess that one solution could be to publish the client app and put the publish output somewhere in the `wwwroot` of the server app, in order to serve it. Not sure if this is being done already somehow... I will try to check....

Comment: A Client and an API can never be "one process". They are meant to run on (very) different hardware.  Your client can run on Android/iOS.  The template with the Hosted option is the most logical way to set things up.  The server does host the Client.  Variations are of coursse allowed.

Comment: This Repo shows you how to run Blazor Server, Blazor WASM and API Controllers from the same site.  There's still two projects, a Web Project and a Library Project. - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/AllinOne.  It may be what you're looking for.

Comment: It would be nice if they made a "dotnet new" template for webapi + blazor client project, e.g. using similar to `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");`. Otherwise you probably manually need to start the web-api, and the blazor dev renderer (similar to `angular serve`.